# How to find the full definition of a method in powershell

Tags: powershell

I just started learning about powershell and I have some trouble finding a full definition of a method for an object. So far I can only show the short definition and the parameter needed using this command on powershell

```
New-Object -ComObject "ActiveBatch.Abatjobscheduler" | Get-Member -Name "search"
```

but I want to check the full description or at least what each of those parameters are used for. Thank you

Comment: that is not a powershell thing. nor is it a windows thing. you will need to dig into the docs for ActiveBatch.

Comment: Ah I see, I thought that since I can call it from Powershell, they would also provide the full documentation of it inside. Thank you for the explanation

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to kinda-sorta help ... [*grin*]